# Python - how to refer main app's variable in app's modules

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I have following files' structure for Flask app (/env is virtual env):

```
/env
/env/bin/...
/env/include/...
/env/lib/...
/env/lib64/...
/env/myapp.py
/mymodules/__init__.py
/mymodules/users/__init__.py
/mymodules/users/controller.py
```

myapp.py has below content:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask
from flask import request, current_app
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import mymodules.users.controller as MyMods


app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# [...]

@app.route(u"/test", methods=['GET'])
def test():

    return MyMods.mytest()

if __name__ == u"__main__":
    app.run()
```

Content of controller.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def mytest():
    return "ok"
```

Question: how can I use `app` and `db` inside controller.py?

I can pass it as param:

```
MyMods.mytest(app, db)

def mytest(app_ref, db_ref):
```

but is it the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it param as you did or could set module level variables:

```
# controller.py
some_var = None
def mytest():
    print(some_var)

# myapp.py
MyMods.some_var = db
...rest of your code...
```

As long as `some_var` gets set before `mytest()` gets called.